# How can I extract data from a line under a header in a text file

Tags: python, file, parsing

I have a text file from which I need to extract certain data. The data I need will appear under a header that begins with "No.". So I know what to look for when searching the file and I can split and print each header. However, I want to extract the data that is on the next line of the one that begins with "No." I cannot use regex either. How can I accomplish this? I was able to successfully locate each header in the file using the below code but as mentioned I want to get the next line.

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if KEYWORD in line:
            data = line.split()
            print(data)
```

prints out the headers:

```
['No.', 'Time', 'Source', 'Destination', 'Protocol', 'Length', 'Info']
['No.', 'Time', 'Source', 'Destination', 'Protocol', 'Length', 'Info']
['No.', 'Time', 'Source', 'Destination', 'Protocol', 'Length', 'Info']
['No.', 'Time', 'Source', 'Destination', 'Protocol', 'Length', 'Info']
['No.', 'Time', 'Source', 'Destination', 'Protocol', 'Length', 'Info']
['No.', 'Time', 'Source', 'Destination', 'Protocol', 'Length', 'Info']
['No.', 'Time', 'Source', 'Destination', 'Protocol', 'Length', 'Info']
```

sample of text file

```
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.180, Dst: 239.255.255.250
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
    Total Length: 358
    Identification: 0xfe2a (65066)
    Flags: 0x4000, Don't fragment
    Time to live: 4
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header checksum: 0xc505 [validation disabled]
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
    Source: 192.168.1.180
    Destination: 239.255.255.250
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 35064, Dst Port: 1900
Simple Service Discovery Protocol

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      2 0.307821       192.168.1.180         239.255.255.250       SSDP     422    NOTIFY * HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to change your code as little as possible, then here's how you can do it:

```
is_next_line_needed = False
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if KEYWORD in line:
            is_next_line_needed = True
        if is_next_line_needed == True:
            data = line.split()
            print(data)
            is_next_line_needed = False
```

Answer (score 0):

only next line.

```python
KEYWORD_check = False
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if KEYWORD_check:
            data = line.split()
            print(data)
            break
        if KEYWORD in line:
            KEYWORD_check = True
```